# Flask Celery task locking

Tags: python, flask, celery, celery-task, flask-cache

I am using Flask with Celery and I am trying to lock a specific task so that it can only be run one at a time. In the celery docs it gives a example of doing this [Celery docs, Ensuring a task is only executed one at a time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html). This example that was given was for Django however I am using flask I have done my best to convert this to work with Flask however I still see myTask1 which has the lock can be run multiple times.

One thing that is not clear to me is if I am using the cache correctly, I have never used it before so all of it is new to me. One thing from the doc's that is mentioned but not explained is this

## Doc Notes:

`In order for this to work correctly you need to be using a cache backend where the .add operation is atomic. memcached is known to work well for this purpose.`

Im not truly sure what that means, should i be using the cache in conjunction with a database and if so how would I do that? I am using mongodb. In my code I just have this setup for the cache `cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})` as that is what was mentioned in the Flask-Cache doc's [Flask-Cache Docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Caching/)

Another thing that is not clear to me is if there is anything different I need to do as I am calling my `myTask1` from within my Flask route `task1`

Here is an example of my code that I am using.

```
from flask import (Flask, render_template, flash, redirect,
                   url_for, session, logging, request, g, render_template_string, jsonify)
from flask_caching import Cache
from contextlib import contextmanager
from celery import Celery
from Flask_celery import make_celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery.five import monotonic
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from hashlib import md5
import pymongo
import time


app = Flask(__name__)

cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
app.config['SECRET_KEY']= 'super secret key for me123456789987654321'

######################
# MONGODB SETUP
#####################
app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'celery-test-db'
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/celery-test-db'


mongo = PyMongo(app)


##############################
# CELERY ARGUMENTS
##############################


app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://localhost//'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/celery-test-db'

app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'mongodb'
app.config['CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS'] = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "celery-test-db", 
    "taskmeta_collection": "celery_jobs",
}

app.config['CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'


celery = Celery('task',broker='mongodb://localhost:27017/jobs')
celery = make_celery(app)


LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 2  # Lock expires in 2 minutes


@contextmanager
def memcache_lock(lock_id, oid):
    timeout_at = monotonic() + LOCK_EXPIRE - 3
    # cache.add fails if the key already exists
    status = cache.add(lock_id, oid, LOCK_EXPIRE)
    try:
        yield status
    finally:
        # memcache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
        # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
        if monotonic() < timeout_at and status:
            # don't release the lock if we exceeded the timeout
            # to lessen the chance of releasing an expired lock
            # owned by someone else
            # also don't release the lock if we didn't acquire it
            cache.delete(lock_id)



@celery.task(bind=True, name='app.myTask1')
def myTask1(self):

    self.update_state(state='IN TASK')

    lock_id = self.name

    with memcache_lock(lock_id, self.app.oid) as acquired:
        if acquired:
            # do work if we got the lock
            print('acquired is {}'.format(acquired))
            self.update_state(state='DOING WORK')
            time.sleep(90)
            return 'result'

    # otherwise, the lock was already in use
    raise self.retry(countdown=60)  # redeliver message to the queue, so the work can be done later



@celery.task(bind=True, name='app.myTask2')
def myTask2(self):
    print('you are in task2')
    self.update_state(state='STARTING')
    time.sleep(120)
    print('task2 done')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/task1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def task1():

    print('running task1')
    result = myTask1.delay()

    # get async task id
    taskResult = AsyncResult(result.task_id)


    # push async taskid into db collection job_task_id
    mongo.db.job_task_id.insert({'taskid': str(taskResult), 'TaskName': 'task1'})

    return render_template('task1.html')


@app.route('/task2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def task2():

    print('running task2')
    result = myTask2.delay()

    # get async task id
    taskResult = AsyncResult(result.task_id)

    # push async taskid into db collection job_task_id
    mongo.db.job_task_id.insert({'taskid': str(taskResult), 'TaskName': 'task2'})

    return render_template('task2.html') 


@app.route('/status', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def status():

    taskid_list = []
    task_state_list = []
    TaskName_list = []

    allAsyncData = mongo.db.job_task_id.find()

    for doc in allAsyncData:
        try:
            taskid_list.append(doc['taskid'])
        except:
            print('error with db conneciton in asyncJobStatus')

        TaskName_list.append(doc['TaskName'])

    # PASS TASK ID TO ASYNC RESULT TO GET TASK RESULT FOR THAT SPECIFIC TASK
    for item in taskid_list:
        try:
            task_state_list.append(myTask1.AsyncResult(item).state)
        except:
            task_state_list.append('UNKNOWN')

    return render_template('status.html', data_list=zip(task_state_list, TaskName_list))
```

## Final Working Code

```
from flask import (Flask, render_template, flash, redirect,
                   url_for, session, logging, request, g, render_template_string, jsonify)
from flask_caching import Cache
from contextlib import contextmanager
from celery import Celery
from Flask_celery import make_celery
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from celery.five import monotonic
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from hashlib import md5
import pymongo
import time
import redis
from flask_redis import FlaskRedis


app = Flask(__name__)

# ADDING REDIS
redis_store = FlaskRedis(app)

# POINTING CACHE_TYPE TO REDIS
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis'})
app.config['SECRET_KEY']= 'super secret key for me123456789987654321'

######################
# MONGODB SETUP
#####################
app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'celery-test-db'
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/celery-test-db'


mongo = PyMongo(app)


##############################
# CELERY ARGUMENTS
##############################

# CELERY USING REDIS
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/celery-test-db'

app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'mongodb'
app.config['CELERY_MONGODB_BACKEND_SETTINGS'] = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "celery-test-db", 
    "taskmeta_collection": "celery_jobs",
}

app.config['CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'


celery = Celery('task',broker='mongodb://localhost:27017/jobs')
celery = make_celery(app)


LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 2  # Lock expires in 2 minutes


@contextmanager
def memcache_lock(lock_id, oid):
    timeout_at = monotonic() + LOCK_EXPIRE - 3
    print('in memcache_lock and timeout_at is {}'.format(timeout_at))
    # cache.add fails if the key already exists
    status = cache.add(lock_id, oid, LOCK_EXPIRE)
    try:
        yield status
        print('memcache_lock and status is {}'.format(status))
    finally:
        # memcache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
        # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
        if monotonic() < timeout_at and status:
            # don't release the lock if we exceeded the timeout
            # to lessen the chance of releasing an expired lock
            # owned by someone else
            # also don't release the lock if we didn't acquire it
            cache.delete(lock_id)



@celery.task(bind=True, name='app.myTask1')
def myTask1(self):

    self.update_state(state='IN TASK')
    print('dir is {} '.format(dir(self)))

    lock_id = self.name
    print('lock_id is {}'.format(lock_id))

    with memcache_lock(lock_id, self.app.oid) as acquired:
        print('in memcache_lock and lock_id is {} self.app.oid is {} and acquired is {}'.format(lock_id, self.app.oid, acquired))
        if acquired:
            # do work if we got the lock
            print('acquired is {}'.format(acquired))
            self.update_state(state='DOING WORK')
            time.sleep(90)
            return 'result'

    # otherwise, the lock was already in use
    raise self.retry(countdown=60)  # redeliver message to the queue, so the work can be done later



@celery.task(bind=True, name='app.myTask2')
def myTask2(self):
    print('you are in task2')
    self.update_state(state='STARTING')
    time.sleep(120)
    print('task2 done')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/task1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def task1():

    print('running task1')
    result = myTask1.delay()

    # get async task id
    taskResult = AsyncResult(result.task_id)


    # push async taskid into db collection job_task_id
    mongo.db.job_task_id.insert({'taskid': str(taskResult), 'TaskName': 'myTask1'})

    return render_template('task1.html')


@app.route('/task2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def task2():

    print('running task2')
    result = myTask2.delay()

    # get async task id
    taskResult = AsyncResult(result.task_id)

    # push async taskid into db collection job_task_id
    mongo.db.job_task_id.insert({'taskid': str(taskResult), 'TaskName': 'task2'})

    return render_template('task2.html')

@app.route('/status', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def status():

    taskid_list = []
    task_state_list = []
    TaskName_list = []

    allAsyncData = mongo.db.job_task_id.find()

    for doc in allAsyncData:
        try:
            taskid_list.append(doc['taskid'])
        except:
            print('error with db conneciton in asyncJobStatus')

        TaskName_list.append(doc['TaskName'])

    # PASS TASK ID TO ASYNC RESULT TO GET TASK RESULT FOR THAT SPECIFIC TASK
    for item in taskid_list:
        try:
            task_state_list.append(myTask1.AsyncResult(item).state)
        except:
            task_state_list.append('UNKNOWN')

    return render_template('status.html', data_list=zip(task_state_list, TaskName_list))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key for me123456789987654321'
    app.run(port=1234, host='localhost')
```

Here is also a screen shot you can see that I ran `myTask1` two times and myTask2 a single time. Now I have the expected behavior for myTask1. Now `myTask1` will be run by a single worker if another worker attempt to pick it up it will just keep retrying based on whatever i define.

[image: Flower Dashboard]

Comment: `self` is a string, and `self.cache` doesn't exist. Just a guess but maybe the `Cache.add` should be an instance so something like: `Cache().add` ? Because when `add` get's called the first argument might be self like `def add(self, lock_id, oid, lock_expire):` so self is the lock_id with how you have it?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I gave it a try status = Cache().add(lock_id, oid, LOCK_EXPIRE) however that gave me a new traceback.

Comment: with memcache_lock(lock_id, self.app.oid) as acquired:
  File "/auto/pysw/cel63/python/3.4.1/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "app.py", line 63, in memcache_lock
    status = Cache().add(lock_id, oid, LOCK_EXPIRE)
  File "/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_cache/__init__.py", line 204, in add
    self.cache.add(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/ws/mastarke-sjc/pyats2/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_cache/__init__.py", line 192, in cache
    return app.extensions['cache'][self]
KeyError: 'cache'

Comment: What is the behavior you want when the task is called multiple times? Do you want the task to be queued or to be ignored entirely?

Comment: Ideally what I would like is when `myTask1` is called it would just be queued and not run until the lock is complete.

Comment: Let me re-clarify incase my first comment is not clear. if `myTask1` is not in use then I would like it to be run. If another worker is using `myTask1` ideally i would like the task to be queued but not run until the lock is removed. hopefully that is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found this to be a surprisingly hard problem. Inspired mainly by [Sebastian's work](https://breadcrumbscollector.tech/what-is-celery-beat-and-how-to-use-it-part-2-patterns-and-caveats/) on implementing a distributed locking algorithm in redis I wrote up a [decorator function](https://gist.github.com/aaronpolhamus/cb305a3350f943215d00b66c85f576ea).

A key point to bear in mind about this approach is that we lock tasks at the level of the task's argument space, e.g. we allow multiple game update/process order tasks to run concurrently, but only one per game. That's what `argument_signature` achieves in the code below. You can see documentation on how we use this in our stack at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aaronpolhamus/cb305a3350f943215d00b66c85f576ea):

```
import base64
from contextlib import contextmanager
import json
import pickle as pkl
import uuid

from backend.config import Config
from redis import StrictRedis
from redis_cache import RedisCache
from redlock import Redlock

rds = StrictRedis(Config.REDIS_HOST, decode_responses=True, charset="utf-8")
rds_cache = StrictRedis(Config.REDIS_HOST, decode_responses=False, charset="utf-8")
redis_cache = RedisCache(redis_client=rds_cache, prefix="rc", serializer=pkl.dumps, deserializer=pkl.loads)
dlm = Redlock([{"host": Config.REDIS_HOST}])

TASK_LOCK_MSG = "Task execution skipped -- another task already has the lock"
DEFAULT_ASSET_EXPIRATION = 8 * 24 * 60 * 60  # by default keep cached values around for 8 days
DEFAULT_CACHE_EXPIRATION = 1 * 24 * 60 * 60  # we can keep cached values around for a shorter period of time

REMOVE_ONLY_IF_OWNER_SCRIPT = """
if redis.call("get",KEYS[1]) == ARGV[1] then
    return redis.call("del",KEYS[1])
else
    return 0
end
"""


@contextmanager
def redis_lock(lock_name, expires=60):
    # https://breadcrumbscollector.tech/what-is-celery-beat-and-how-to-use-it-part-2-patterns-and-caveats/
    random_value = str(uuid.uuid4())
    lock_acquired = bool(
        rds.set(lock_name, random_value, ex=expires, nx=True)
    )
    yield lock_acquired
    if lock_acquired:
        rds.eval(REMOVE_ONLY_IF_OWNER_SCRIPT, 1, lock_name, random_value)


def argument_signature(*args, **kwargs):
    arg_list = [str(x) for x in args]
    kwarg_list = [f"{str(k)}:{str(v)}" for k, v in kwargs.items()]
    return base64.b64encode(f"{'_'.join(arg_list)}-{'_'.join(kwarg_list)}".encode()).decode()


def task_lock(func=None, main_key="", timeout=None):
    def _dec(run_func):
        def _caller(*args, **kwargs):
            with redis_lock(f"{main_key}_{argument_signature(*args, **kwargs)}", timeout) as acquired:
                if not acquired:
                    return TASK_LOCK_MSG
                return run_func(*args, **kwargs)
        return _caller
    return _dec(func) if func is not None else _dec
```

Implementation in our task definitions file:

```
@celery.task(name="async_test_task_lock")
@task_lock(main_key="async_test_task_lock", timeout=UPDATE_GAME_DATA_TIMEOUT)
def async_test_task_lock(game_id):
    print(f"processing game_id {game_id}")
    time.sleep(TASK_LOCK_TEST_SLEEP)
```

How we test against a local celery cluster:

```
from backend.tasks.definitions import async_test_task_lock, TASK_LOCK_TEST_SLEEP
from backend.tasks.redis_handlers import rds, TASK_LOCK_MSG
class TestTaskLocking(TestCase):
    def test_task_locking(self):
        rds.flushall()
        res1 = async_test_task_lock.delay(3)
        res2 = async_test_task_lock.delay(5)
        self.assertFalse(res1.ready())
        self.assertFalse(res2.ready())
        res3 = async_test_task_lock.delay(5)
        res4 = async_test_task_lock.delay(5)
        self.assertEqual(res3.get(), TASK_LOCK_MSG)
        self.assertEqual(res4.get(), TASK_LOCK_MSG)
        time.sleep(TASK_LOCK_TEST_SLEEP)
        res5 = async_test_task_lock.delay(3)
        self.assertFalse(res5.ready())
```

(as a goodie there's also a quick example of how to setup a `redis_cache`)

Answer (score 7):

In your question, you point out this warning from the Celery example you used:

> In order for this to work correctly you need to be using a cache backend where the `.add` operation is atomic. `memcached` is known to work well for this purpose.

And you mention that you don't really understand what this means. Indeed, the code you show demonstrates that you've not heeded that warning, because **your code uses an inappropriate backend.**

Consider this code:

```
with memcache_lock(lock_id, self.app.oid) as acquired:
    if acquired:
        # do some work
```

What you want here is for `acquired` to be true only for one thread at a time. If two threads enter the `with` block at the same time, only one should "win" and have `acquired` be true. This thread that has `acquired` true can then proceed with its work, and the other thread has to skip doing the work and try again later to acquire the lock. **In order to ensure that only one thread can have `acquired` true, `.add` must be atomic.**

Here's some pseudo code of what `.add(key, value)` does:

```
1. if <key> is already in the cache:
2.   return False    
3. else:
4.   set the cache so that <key> has the value <value>
5.   return True
```

If the execution of `.add` is not atomic, this could happen if two threads A and B execute `.add("foo", "bar")`. Assume an empty cache at the start.

1. Thread A executes `1. if "foo" is already in the cache` and finds that `"foo"` is not in the cache, and jumps to line 3 but the thread scheduler switches control to thread B.
2. Thread B also executes `1. if "foo" is already in the cache`, and *also* finds that "foo" is not in the cache. So it jumps to line 3 and then executes line 4 and 5 which sets the key `"foo"` to the value `"bar"` and the call returns `True`.
3. Eventually, the scheduler gives control back to Thread A, which continues executing 3, 4, 5 and also sets the key `"foo"` to the value `"bar"` and also returns `True`.

What you have here is two `.add` calls that return `True`, if these `.add` calls are made within `memcache_lock` this entails that two threads can have `acquired` be true. So two threads could do work at the same time, and your `memcache_lock` is not doing what it should be doing, which is only allow one thread to work at a time.

**You are not using a cache that ensures that `.add` is atomic**. You initialize it like this:

```
cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})
```

The [`simple` backend](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Caching/#simplecache) is scoped to a single process, has no thread-safety, and has an `.add` operation which is not atomic. (This does not involve Mongo at all by the way. If you wanted your cache to be backed by Mongo, you'd have to specify a backed specifically made to send data to a Mongo database.)

So you have to switch to another backend, one that guarantees that `.add` is atomic. You could follow the lead of the Celery example and use the [`memcached` backend](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Caching/#memcachedcache), which does have an atomic `.add` operation. I don't use Flask, but I've does essentially what you are doing with Django and Celery, and used the Redis backend successfully to provide the kind of locking you're using here.

Comment: Ok so rather than using the simple cache like so `cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})` I should switch to using a Redis cache like `cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis'})` Right now I use RabbitMQ but I could switch to Redis if this is what is required for this to work.

Comment: Yes, you could use `cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis'})` if you want to use Redis. I know RabbitMQ by name but I've never actually used it, so I don't know if it would be appropriate as a backend for locking.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't see RabbitMQ mentioned on the official Flask-Cache Doc's for Built-in Cache Backend, but I do see Redis. Let me setup Redis in my environment and see how that goes.  If that works I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thanks again for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks you, I was able to finally get this to work. Basically needed to use Redis I changed to `cache = Cache(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis'})` and now this works.

Answer (score 1):

With this setup, you should still expect to see workers receiving the task, since the lock is checked inside of the task itself. The only difference will be that the work won't be performed if the lock is acquired by another worker.
In the example given in the docs, this is the desired behavior; if a lock already exists, the task will simply do nothing and finish as successful. What you want is slightly different; you want the work to be queued up instead of ignored.

In order to get the desired effect, you would need to make sure that the task will be picked up by a worker and performed some time in the future. One way to accomplish this would be with retrying.

```
@task(bind=True, name='my-task')
def my_task(self):
    lock_id = self.name

    with memcache_lock(lock_id, self.app.oid) as acquired:
        if acquired:
            # do work if we got the lock
            print('acquired is {}'.format(acquired))
            return 'result'

    # otherwise, the lock was already in use
    raise self.retry(countdown=60)  # redeliver message to the queue, so the work can be done later
```

Comment: Thanks I see your point and appreciate your help. However I still see I am able to call this multiple times. When I look at the worker logs you can see both worker 3 and 4 picked up myTask1 at around the same time. `140> tail -f worker-3.log
[2018-12-28 12:51:55,849: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] acquired is True
[2018-12-28 12:53:25,943: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task app.myTask1[5f492c3f-9684-493e-8873-1190f71527a5] succeeded in 90.10438371099985s: 'result'`

Comment: Here is worker 4 logs `141> tail -f worker-4.log
[2018-12-28 12:51:59,381: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-4] acquired is True
[2018-12-28 12:53:29,476: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task app.myTask1[be05682f-1ff4-452b-9dff-c4593bd3c452] succeeded in 90.11584289799998s: 'result'`

Comment: you can see they both pick up myTask1 around '12:53'

Comment: I updated my post to show myTask1 with your solution.

Comment: It would indicate to me then that the `memcache_lock` is not functioning as expected. I'm not familiar witth `flask-cache` but I would wonder what the value is returned when you `.add` an existing key. Additionally, it looks like flask-cache is bound to the request context? Also according to the docs, the 'simple' cache is just a Python dictionary. Maybe you could try to configure an actual memcached cache instead.

Comment: Thanks i was thinking in the same way. However I have never used Flask-Cache or any type of memcache so Im not really sure what to do there. But I think your idea is in the right direction. ill look into the Flask-Cache and memcache.

Comment: I added my route code to my original post. Originally I was not sure if it was relevant or not. I think the cache issue may have to do with how I am calling the task. If you see in my added code the task is getting executed by going to a particular route. in this example I have a route called task1 that will execute myTask1. I think maybe the cache issue might have to do with this.